# Error HH8 Invalid account: #0 for network: bsctest - Expected string, received undefined

Tags: contract-deployment

i'm following this tutorial

https://github.com/KelvinThai/PancakeSwapFork/commit/39aa3a21aea481a17ee0da6160054ada2bba6f71?diff=unified#diff-67919482ae3e6bff3f0c6b33a25ff6553643d2d63aa9980fd238d223b3020535

but i get the following problem,

Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

- Invalid account: #0 for network: bsctest - Expected string, received undefined
- Invalid account: #0 for network: bsc - Expected string, received undefined

To learn more about Hardhat's configuration, please go to https://hardhat.org/config/

When i try to "npx hardhat run script/deploy.js --network bsctest"

this is what my hardhat.config.js looks like,

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require('dotenv').config();
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan');


// This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
// https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.6.12",
  networks: {
    dev: {
        url: "http://localhost:7545",
        gasPrice: 20,
        saveDeployments: true
    },
    bsctest: {
        url: "https://data-seed-prebsc-2-s2.binance.org:8545/",
        accounts: [process.env.PRIV_KEY],
        gasPrice: 10000000000,
        blockGasLimit: 1000000
    },
    bsc: {
        url: "https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org/",
        accounts: [process.env.PRIV_KEY],
        gasPrice: 5100000000,
        blockGasLimit: 1000000
    }
},
etherscan:{
  apiKey:process.env.API_KEY
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

just comment out this two it will work

```
bsctest: {
        url: "https://data-seed-prebsc-2-s2.binance.org:8545/",
        accounts: [process.env.PRIV_KEY],
        gasPrice: 10000000000,
        blockGasLimit: 1000000
    },
    bsc: {
        url: "https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org/",
        accounts: [process.env.PRIV_KEY],
        gasPrice: 5100000000,
        blockGasLimit: 1000000
    }
```

It's not working because your.env is not setup.